# Simpleitk: Can I use single label for multiple images in one step?

Tags: simpleitk

I have a label which I want to apply for 4 co-registered images to obtain the mean value of the label on each of them. Currently, I have to write the code 4 times.

My current code is

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import numpy as np

label = sitk.ReadImage('segmentation.nii.gz')
image1 = sitk.ReadImage('image1.nii')
image2 = sitk.ReadImage('image2.nii')
image3 = sitk.ReadImage('image3.nii')
image4 = sitk.ReadImage('image4.nii')

labelstatsFilter = sitk.LabelStatisticsImageFilter()
labelstatsFilter.SetUseHistograms(True)

labelstatsFilter.Execute(image1, label)
labelstatsFilter.GetMean(1)

labelstatsFilter.Execute(image2, label)
labelstatsFilter.GetMean(1)

labelstatsFilter.Execute(image3, label)
labelstatsFilter.GetMean(1)

labelstatsFilter.Execute(image4, label)
labelstatsFilter.GetMean(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop, but you'd still be using the LabelStatisticsImageFilter 4 times.  There isn't a way to have 1 Execute call calculate the statistics over 4 different images.

Here's what a looped version of the code would look like:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
label = sitk.ReadImage('segmentation.nii.gz')

images = []
means  = []
labelstatsFilter = sitk.LabelStatisticsImageFilter()
labelstatsFilter.SetUseHistograms(True)

for i in range(4):
     images.append( sitk.ReadImage('image'+str(i)+'.nii') )
     labelstatsFilter.Execute( images[i], label )
     means.append( labelstatsFilter.GetMean(1) )
```